# Instantiate parameterized class using a field type of another class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, parameterized

I would like to use a type which I get from a class' field (using reflection) to instantiate a class with generics.
Note: I omitted the exceptions hoping for easy reading.

```
public class AClass   {
    class BClass<T>   {
        T aMemba;
    }

    public void AMethod()   {
        Class c = Class.forName("com.bla.flipper");
        Field f = c.getField("flipIt");

        // Here is my difficulty, I want to instantiate BClass with the type of
        // field 'f' but the compiler won't let me.
        Class typeClass = f.getType();
        BClass<typeClass> = new BClass<typeClass>();
    }
}
```

Is what I want to achieve reasonable? Any thought on how I can solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: A lot of things are "reasonable"... a sledge hammer is reasonable for driving a pole into the ground, but not as a fly swatter. So if you're driving a pole into the ground, then it's reasonable to use a sledge hammer. If you want to instantiate a class based on the field type of a class where the field may change type, then it's reasonable to use reflection.

Comment: A fundamental thing you need to learn **right now** if you want to use generics in Java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the type argument of the type of typeClass:

```
Field f = ...;
Class<?> typeClass = f.getType();
withClassCapture(typeClass);

private <T> void withClassCapture(Class<T> klazz) {
    BClass<T> instance = new BClass<T>();
    // ... do your thing
}
```

Comment: Ben, thanks for the snippet. I like it very much, never thought we can do the trick like that.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are trying to do is not reasonable because if you look at the following line:

```
BClass<typeClass> = new BClass<typeClass>();
```

`typeClass` is something that compiler should be aware of. But in your case it's only known in the runtime through reflection.

Compiler needs to erase `T` in `BClass<T>` and replace it with a concrete type which in your case is unknown at compile time so logically it's invalid.

Comment: Thank you Bhesh, the most logical explanation I came across with.